# Log of column based on another columns condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way using pandas to apply a log to a column B if column A equals for example "twitter" and "pinterest"?

For example this is a very simplified version of my dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import math
df = pd.DataFrame({'platform':[facebook,twitter,snapchat,twitter,pinterest],'b':[13,1000,21,1300,500]})
```

Comment: a logarithm to the numeric values

Answer (score 0):

For example if your `condition` is `df["platform"] == "facebook"`, you can create an apply function with statement.

**Try this:**

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.log(x["b"]) if condition else x["b"], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use vectorial code with boolean indexing:

```
import numpy as np
df['b'] = df['b'].mask(df['platform'].isin(['twitter', 'pinterest']), np.log(df['b']))
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df['platform'].isin(['twitter', 'pinterest']), 'b'] = np.log(df['b'])
```

Output:

```
    platform          b
0   facebook  13.000000
1    twitter   6.907755
2   snapchat  21.000000
3    twitter   7.170120
4  pinterest        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help

`df[df.platform.isin(['twitter','pinterest'])].b.apply(lambda b : np.log(b))`

Comment: Using `apply` should be avoided when you have a vectorized alternative ;)